# Earth Engine export TIFF dimensions?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export a series of square images, but I can't seem to understand what's driving the dimensions of the final file. Here is my workflow:

```
region = PointOfInterest.buffer(200).bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(
  image = NaipImagery,
  description = 'square_export',
  fileNamePrefix = 'square_export',
  bucket = 'my-bucket-name',
  scale = 1,
  region = region)
task.start()
```

I expect the output to be a 400x400 pixel square. But instead it is a random number of pixels, that changes depending on which PointOfInterest I am using. Here are the details of one such exported image:

```
im.size = (504, 401)
im.tile = [
 ('tiff_lzw', (0, 0, 256, 256), 758, 'RGBA'),
 ('tiff_lzw', (256, 0, 512, 256), 266517, 'RGBA'),
 ('tiff_lzw', (0, 256, 256, 512), 495006, 'RGBA'),
 ('tiff_lzw', (256, 256, 512, 512), 617484, 'RGBA')]
```

Frustratingly, You can see that the tiles go all the way to 512px in each direction, while the size is far smaller than that. Why?!? Other PointsOfInterest are (503, 402), or (503, 401), or...

The result is that I can't display the image, without getting the following error:

```
display(im)
ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to export a square image, that has the right size and tiles that allow it to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buffer(200)` means buffering **to a 200 meter circle**. Depending on the projection you are using and *where on the globe you are*, 200 meters does not mean 200 pixels, because the earth is not flat and so a projection must distort distances in a position-dependent way. `scale: 1` only means 1 pixel = 1 meter if you are exactly on the equator (in most projections).

- If you want images of a reliable size, you can specify `dimensions` *instead of* `scale`. Writing `dimensions: 400` will produce an image whose maximum dimension is always at most 400 pixels.
- You may also want to define the region using `ee.Geometry.Rectangle()` and specify the corner points directly, in the projection you are going to export, rather than using `buffer()`. (There is probably a good way to express “400 projected units around this point” but I don't know it offhand and don't have time to research this answer more right now.)

Comment: Thank you so much @Kevin Reid! Your suggestion of using dimensions was exactly what I needed.
I still can't figure out how to get an arbitrarily-sized image. If the dimensions are not a multiple of 256 pixels, then I still get the "ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image". That happens even if I have changed the shardSize to match my dimensions.

Comment: @curiouserand That error appears to be a bug in PIL (not Earth Engine), which I assume you are using, according to this old message https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/p8zcATYB5lU/BQ783E1bBQAJ which suggests using another file format for export, or transcoding the file using another tool (e.g. just `gdal_translate in.tif out.tif` will rewrite the file without tiles).

Comment: you've gone above and beyond. I am using PIL, and I had not seen that thread, but sure enough--a simple gdal_translate corrected the image (which is now the right dimension), and made it ingestible as intended! Thanks again!